# Is Firebase Realtime Database key generation reliable to clock change on Android/iOS devices? #AskFirebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

## TL; DR

[Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) uses a push ID with a [chronological prefix](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html), thus new objects are always sorted by its creation timestamp.

Given offline capabilities is enable on [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) and [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) app, if the user has disabled the automatic clock synchronization, will the SDK:

1. Detect the change and adjust the prefix when the connection is recovered?
2. Obey the clock change and create an ID with a *bad* prefix?

## Details

### [The Bolsonaro's Daylight Saving Time Bug](https://dev.to/arthurmde/the-bolsonaro-s-bug-the-end-of-daylight-saving-time-in-brazil-may-affect-your-system-2e38)

In 2019 Brazilian government canceled Daylight Saving Time without giving the proper time to carriers and internet providers get prepared to it. Consequently clocks were automatically advanced, crashing several distributed systems in Brazil due timestamp inconsistency. This phenomena is popular known as [**Bolsonaro's Bug**](https://dev.to/arthurmde/the-bolsonaro-s-bug-the-end-of-daylight-saving-time-in-brazil-may-affect-your-system-2e38).

Desperate because they were no longer receiving orders from customers, they turned off the automatic clock adjustment and set it manually, users who depends on their mobile devices for work (ex. taxi drivers, deliverer professionals, etc) turned off the automatic clock update on their devices and **manually turned their block back in 1 hour**. Thus:

1. If you live in Rio de Janeiro, the **GMT-3** would be updated to **GMT-2** during daylight saving time, but **UTC** would not change (so far, so good).
2. Turning of the automatic update and manually subtracting 1 hour *to fix the bug* messed with the **device UTC**, i.e. it is 1 hour behind the **real UTC**.

### Question

The scenario is problematic when the user save data offline (with a bad clock) and hours later tries to sync with the server.

Since Firebase Realtime Database has [offline capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) and [push IDs are chronologically sorted](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html), in this very specific scenario, would it be possible to:

1. Inform the SDK about this delay to the correct UTC time?
2. Help the SDK to fix the push IDs generated offline and update their timestamp prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inaccurate local clock could cause inaccurate push IDs, in terms of time ordering.  If you need accurate times for the purpose of sorting, I wouldn't rely too heavily on the ordering of push IDs.

You might want to read the documentation on [clock skew](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#clock-skew) for more information on what you can do to deal with possible time differences:

> While firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is much more accurate,
>   and preferable for most read/write operations, it can occasionally be
>   useful to estimate the client's clock skew with respect to the
>   Firebase Realtime Database's servers. You can attach a callback to the
>   location /.info/serverTimeOffset to obtain the value, in milliseconds,
>   that Firebase Realtime Database clients add to the local reported time
>   (epoch time in milliseconds) to estimate the server time. Note that
>   this offset's accuracy can be affected by networking latency, and so
>   is useful primarily for discovering large (> 1 second) discrepancies
>   in clock time.
>
> ```
> DatabaseReference offsetRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset");
> offsetRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
>         double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
>         double estimatedServerTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
>         Log.w(TAG, "Listener was cancelled");
>     }
> });
> ```

Comment: In 2019 Brazilian government canceled Daylight Saving Time without giving the proper time to carriers and internet providers get prepared to it. Consequently clocks were automatically advanced, crashing several distributed systems in Brazil due timestamp inconsistency. Thus we are trying to at least inform the SDK about the change and do the proper key timestamp adjustment.

Comment: @JPVentura Timestamps shouldn't change at all due to changes in timezone definitions.  A timestamp is just a number that describes a point in time for everyone on the planet.  It doesn't have any tz information encoded into it.  Changing (or redefining) the timezone on a device doesn't change absolute time, it just changes how the timestamp would be rendered as a human-readable date, for a particular timezone.

Comment: Updated the description, but you can find more details at https://dev.to/arthurmde/the-bolsonaro-s-bug-the-end-of-daylight-saving-time-in-brazil-may-affect-your-system-2e38